# ¿Es posible establecer una relación 1:3 o 1:5 en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Dentro de  la documentación que soy capaz de encontrar en la web sobre relaciones en una base de datos encuentro 1 a 1, 1 a varios y varios a varios. Pero yo quisiera saber si es posible establecer una relación por ejemplo 1 a 5, ésto es para que una tabla no me permita, de alguna manera, establecer 5 relaciones con otra.

Por ejemplo, tengo una tabla llamada "equipos" y otra "jugadores" y un equipo solo puede tener un máximo de 5 jugadores, ni uno más. En una relación 1 a varios puedo por error meter más de éstos jugadores.

¿Cómo lo puedo hacer?

Comment: Podrías usar un disparador (trigger) o procedimientos almacenados para hacer la comprobación antes de hacer el insert. O pasar de la base de datos y controlarlo en la propia aplicación. Hasta donde sé, no es posible limitar el número de relaciones entre tablas.

Comment: No le pongas un corsé a tu base de datos, controla en el código de la aplicación que antes del `INSERT` si ya en el equipo hay 5 jugadores que no inserte más. Eso sería una función con 2 ó 3 líneas en el código, ¿para qué complicarse con la bd o para qué complicar a la bd?

Answer (score 5):

Como dice @Muriano no es posible limitar el número de relaciones en mysql, pero si usar un trigger .

El ejemplo seria así:

```
CREATE TABLE SEASSON(
  ID INT  AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  YEAR_BEGIN INT UNIQUE,
  YEAR_END INT UNIQUE,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO SEASSON (YEAR_BEGIN,YEAR_END) VALUES (2017,2018);
INSERT INTO SEASSON (YEAR_BEGIN,YEAR_END) VALUES (2018,2019);


CREATE TABLE TEAM (
  ID INT  AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  NAME VARCHAR(250) UNIQUE,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO TEAM (NAME) VALUES ('Team A'),('Team B'),('Team C');


CREATE TABLE PLAYER(
  ID INT  AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  NAME VARCHAR(250),
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;


INSERT INTO PLAYER (NAME) VALUES ('Player 1') ,('Player 2'),('Player 3'),('Player 4'),('Player 5'),('Player 6') ,('Player 7'),('Player 8'),('Player 9'),('Player 10'),('Player 11');


CREATE TABLE INSCRIPTION(
  ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  SEASSON_ID INT NOT NULL,
  TEAM_ID INT NOT NULL,
  PLAYER_ID INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (SEASSON_ID)
        REFERENCES SEASSON(ID)
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (TEAM_ID)
        REFERENCES TEAM(ID)
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (PLAYER_ID)
        REFERENCES PLAYER(ID)
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
  UNIQUE KEY `inscription_by_seasson_and_player` (`SEASSON_ID`,`PLAYER_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;


INSERT INTO INSCRIPTION (SEASSON_ID,TEAM_ID,PLAYER_ID) VALUES (1,1,1),(1,1,2),(1,1,3),(1,1,4),(1,1,5),(1,2,6),(1,2,7),(1,2,8),(1,2,9),(1,2,10);

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW vw_people_on_teams as (
  SELECT 
    COUNT(p.NAME) as 'Number of players',
    t.NAME as 'Team Name',
    CONCAT(s.YEAR_BEGIN,'-',s.YEAR_END)   as 'Seasson'

  FROM INSCRIPTION as i LEFT JOIN TEAM as t on i.TEAM_ID =  t.ID 
  LEFT JOIN PLAYER as p on p.ID = i.PLAYER_ID LEFT JOIN SEASSON as s on s.ID = i.SEASSON_ID
  GROUP BY t.NAME , s.YEAR_BEGIN,s.YEAR_END
);
```

Hasta aquí será algo parecido a lo que tienes, luego creamos el trigger. Verificamos en el si después de insertar debemos borrar el registro o no. Todo esto se ejecuta como una transacción con lo cual en el momento que borramos el registro se hace rollback de la transacción y de ahí el error que devuelve mysql. Básicamente peta porque el trigger utilizó una función que invalida a la función del insert.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER CHECK_5_PLAYERS  AFTER INSERT  ON INSCRIPTION  
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
     IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INSCRIPTION WHERE TEAM_ID = NEW.TEAM_ID AND SEASSON_ID = NEW.SEASSON_ID) > 5  THEN BEGIN
            DELETE FROM INSCRIPTION WHERE ID = NEW.ID ;
     END; END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Tras usar este esquema , con las siguiente tablas , cada vez que quieras inscribir a un jugador en un equipo en el cual para esa temporada ya hay 5 jugadores automáticamente te dará el error siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo al momento de inscribir en otro equipo el cual tiene plazas disponibles  la operación será satisfactoria:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**NOTA*:**
En mi humilde opinión, siempre es mejor dejar estas lógicas en el código de la aplicación y tocar lo menos posible la base de datos. Será más fácil de mantener y modificar cuando haga falta.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Tal y como comenta @A.Cedano , no sería una buena práctica utilizar este trigger.

En el caso de tener una aplicación intermediaria , en PHP , Java , C# ... debe ser esta la que controle y aplique la lógica de la inserción de registros.

¿Cuando es válido el uso de un trigger como este?

Todo depende de el uso que le estemos dando a la base de datos. Es decir , si solo estamos llevando un registro de los equipos de nuestro barrio y no tenemos aplicación intermediaria, sería correcto de usar algo como el trigger. Ya que no sería tan descabellado usarlo sin aplicación intermediaria y nos ahorraría fallos de inserción , tiempo de desarrollo etc.

En el caso de ser una solución completa la lógica debe ir en la capa de aplicación y no en la de la persistencia de datos. Ya que en un futuro podríamos cambiar de sistema de persistencia de datos obligándonos a ejecutar está técnica de nuevo. 
Tambien el uso de esta solución aplicaría un incremento del valor de auto_increment (aunque es un bigint), obligándonos a usar otro campo si quisieramos llevar un correlación de registros.

**USO DE TRIGGER PARA DOBLE VERIFICACIÓN**

Resulta sencillo aplicar toda esta teoría de ***"la lógica solo en la capa de aplicación"*** y no volverse a preguntar nunca si debiéramos usar un trigger.

Pero existe un caso donde esta teoría no sirve del todo, aunque sea un caso muy poco probable, creo que está bien exponerlo.

Supongamos que tenemos un formulario en una web, la cual está siendo observada por dos usuarios de forma concurrente. Los dos rellenan y envían el formulario al mismo tiempo. Esto es casi imposible , así que uno llegará con milésimas de segundos antes que el otro. Mientras que el primero consultaba si la aplicación puede hacer la inserción , el segundo también lo consulta. Obteniendo así los dos permisos desde el backend de la aplicación para hacer su **insert**. La base de datos no tiene restricción alguna así que ambos usuarios han realizado sus inserts sin problema alguno.

Si lo aplicamos al caso del compañero, tendremos 6 jugadores en un equipo que solo debía tener 5. Siendo el único método totalmente restrictivo y eficaz el trigger.

Comment: _Verificamos en el si después de insertar debemos borrar el registro o no. Todo esto se ejecuta como una transacción con lo cual en el momento que borramos el registro se hace rollback de la transacción..._ ¿O sea que el registro se inserta y luego se borra? Si es así me parece una solución mala desde todo punto de vista. Definitivamente, la solución pasa por lo que pones al final: **_En mi humilde opinión, siempre es mejor dejar estas lógicas en el código de la aplicación y tocar lo menos posible la base de datos. Será más fácil de mantener y modificar cuando haga falta._**

Comment: @A.Cedano , correcto , el after insert se ejecuta una vez realizado el insert ,  es decir , si revisamos el campo auto_increment ID de la tabla INSCRIPTION, veremos que cada tras intento no válido el valor auto_increment se ha incrementado en 1 aunque no halla registro. Si que estuvo insertado momentáneamente . Como comentaba lo mejor sería hacerlo en el código de la app y no en la base de datos, pero creo que eso ya lo puse en mi respuesta inicial no ? La cual da respuesta a la pregunta exclusivamente sobre Mysql y como lograrlo con sql.

Comment: Con todo respeto, no es una solución óptima, pues lo que hace es _crear registros fantasma en la base de datos_. Lo grave no es tanto que tengas saltos en la columna autoincremental, sino el coste que tendría tal solución teniendo que introducir registros _fantasma_ o sea, introduciendo registros que luego borrarás posiblemente de inmediato. Además, como comenté en la pregunta, la validación por código a nivel de la app sería no sólo más eficaz desde el punto de vista del rendimiento, sino incluso desde el punto de vista de implementación, pues con 2 ó 3 líneas bastaría para validar los datos.

Comment: Y es que ademas, **por norma**, siempre antes de insertar un registro en la base de datos, **sea la aplicación que sea, la misma debe tener una función que pregunte si dichos datos existen antes de insertarlos**. Actualmente existen clases que lo hacen, pasando a un método de la clase el nombre de la tabla y los datos del índice. (Y si no tienes que crear tu propia clase de validación). Si no, imagina una bd con cientos o miles de tablas en las que para cada una tengas que implementar una solución como la planteada en tu respuesta.

Comment: @A.Cedano, vamos a ver eso yo lo tengo claro , y todo lo que dices amén nunca mejor dicho :D , es lo ideal y como debe de hacerse. Lo que defiendo es la respuesta ante la pregunta en cuestión. También hay que tener en cuenta que algunas soluciones del lado del servidor de base de datos suelen ser más optimas, no es el caso de esta, esta claro. Pero creo que he respondido bien a la pregunta del compañero y no estoy respondiendo a ¿Cómo controlo el limite de inserción de registros con (PHP , C# , Java) a la base de datos? , a parte de que he avisado de que no es lo ideal hacerlo con un trigger.

Comment: Entiendo que tu intención era responder a la pregunta, pero a veces la respuesta pasa por indicar al OP que el problema está mal enfocado. Pues dándole una solución a medias solamente se ofrece la ilusión de que el problema ha sido resuelto. Sigo insistiendo que en este caso el problema se resuelve con unas pocas líneas de código. Y no sólo éste problema, sino cualquier otro que requiera validación. Si usamos PHP, una función como: `function isValid($parametros) {... validar parámetros; ...retornar true o false ...}` Y lo mismo para el lenguaje que sea.

Comment: @A.Cedano a parte de debatir otra respuesta, ni si quiera le das tú ,tu propia respuesta.Si yo veo una respuesta que no me cuadra escribo la mía para que al menos el compañero tenga varios puntos de vista y opciones a elegir.Se trata de construir y ayudar no abrir debates en la respuestas de los demás.Para eso está la puntuación por respuesta.Si la tuya es más buena con el tiempo la gente te lo reconocerá y subirá por encima de las demás respuestas.Yo me limito a ayudar cuando puedo y ya avise de que no era lo más ideal desde un principio, solo has repetido mi nota como si no la hubiese puesto

Comment: Si el OP no ha indicado qué lenguaje está usando ni ha indicado que está dispuesto a cambiar el enfoque del problema que para mí es el verdadero problema no puedo aventurarme a ofrecer una respuesta. No te sientas atacado, no es mi intención. Creo que en ciertos casos, como este, el problema está en el enfoque que el OP le está dando. Él se hace la ilusión de resolverlo de esta manera pero la semana próxima surge un nuevo requerimiento, por ejemplo, que el equipo acepte solo 5 jugadores pero no mayores de 30 años. Ahí tendremos de nuevo al OP perdido, preguntando de nuevo algo casi similar.

Comment: @A.Cedano está claro que dependiendo de la pregunta podremos ayudar hacia un lado u otro , y a algunas preguntas les falta aclarar muchas cosas , no creo que sea este el caso. Si  lo fuese ¿porque no le has pedido los requerimientos que te hacían falta para ayudarle y escribir una respuesta ? Y no me siento atacado, pero todo lo que has puesto en los comentarios podría ir como respuesta. Le serviría a más gente y te votarían la respuesta para que esté antes de la mía.

Comment: No se trata de _votos_. Se trata de ayudar al OP de la mejor manera. :) Saludos.